# How to get the last value from jmeter Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, jmeter

[image]

I have used regular expression with the following configuration to extract **id** value:

```
Regex: `"id":"(.*?)"\,"batch":{"id":"(.*?)"}` 
Template is `$1$` 
match value is `N`
```

but I am not getting last value I am getting value on a random basis. please suggest how to get last id value.

The response is given below and wants to extract `N1600-2016-11-18-1479503469487` value from the response.

```
14T21:00:00Z","version":1479157741885,"recordCount":92054,"statusIdentifier":"END"},{"id":"N1600-2016-11-15-1479244284441","batch":{"id":"N1600"},"asOf":"2016-11-15T21:00:00Z","runDate":"2016-11-15T21:00:00Z","version":1479244284441,"recordCount":91838,"statusIdentifier":"END"},{"id":"N1600-2016-11-16-1479330679449","batch":{"id":"N1600"},"asOf":"2016-11-16T21:00:00Z","runDate":"2016-11-16T21:00:00Z","version":1479330679449,"recordCount":91796,"statusIdentifier":"END"},{"id":"N1600-2016-11-17-1479417271814","batch":{"id":"N1600"},"asOf":"2016-11-17T21:00:00Z","runDate":"2016-11-17T21:00:00Z","version":1479417271814,"recordCount":91761,"statusIdentifier":"END"},{"id":"N1600-2016-11-18-1479503469487","batch":{"id":"N1600"},"asOf":"2016-11-18T21:00:00Z","runDate":"2016-11-18T21:00:00Z","version":1479503469487,"recordCount":91693,"statusIdentifier":"END"}]
```

After adding Beanshell

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**A.** If you are sure that Nth element (say 4th) is the `last value every time`, then you can `hard code` the value in `Match no. as 4`.

**B.** If you are not sure it is always Nth (4) element, then do as follows:

Mention following values in RegExExtractor:

```
Regex: `"id":"(.*?)"\,"batch":{"id":"(.*?)"}` 
Template is `$1$` 
match value is -1  // to store all matched values
```

Add BeanShell PostProcessor as a child to the same sampler and add the following code:

```
int size = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("ID_matchNr")); // to get size of matched values
log.info("size:" + size ); // you can remove log stmts once it is working
String newId = "ID_" + size;
String lastId = vars.get(newId); // to retrieve the value
log.info("last id: " + lastId);
vars.put("lastID", lastId); // to store the value
```

you can refer the last value as follows:

```
${lastID}
```

Reference Image:

RegExExtractor:

[image]

BeanShell PostProcessor:

[image]

Comment: getting this exception Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``int size = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("ID_matchNr")); log.info("size:" + size );  . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Integer.parseInt

Comment: can you share the screenshot how you added the code? Added image, please use it as reference

Comment: image has been added

Comment: Add BeanShell **Postprocessor** but not Sampler. under getSnapShot sampler.

Comment: added but still getting error Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``int size = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("ID_matchNr")); // to get size of matched v . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Integer.parseInt

Comment: keep the reference name as "ID" but not "ID_MatchNr".  "ID_MatchNr" gives the number of matches.

Comment: Regular Expression Extractor with match no -1 not working i am getting default value

Comment: can you add Debug sampler and verify the same using View Results Tree? Added image for Reg Ex Extractor. You need to change from "ID_MatchNr" to "ID" in ONLY RegExExtractor. In BeanShell, it must be "ID_MacthNr"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you parse the response as a JSON Object? It's going to be more maintainable than using regular expressions if your json object is modified in a future.

Comment: i am using old jmeter version create a new version will effects my previous scripts could you please suggest how can i do it with regular expression